# Coin Toss: Expectations of number of heads up

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I have a probability question here. Suppose I throw a coin and I stop when I have a pair of "up" and "down". I want to calculate the expectation of the number of "up" before I got a pair.  Here is my strategy:

Suppose we have $k$ heads ups, before we get a pair. And we will have 
$$
\mathbb{E}(k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k(\frac{1}{2})^k(1/2) = 2/2 = 1
$$

So the expectation value of k will be $1$, which means we only need to have one heads up when we get a pair of up and down. Does that seems right?

Comment: Does the order of "up"and "down" matter? I.e. are UD and DU both accepted as pair "up" and "down" or only UD?

Comment: What do you mean by "before"? If the sequence is DDU, does the U come "before" the pair, or at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $1$ up is required, the sequence needed is either $UD$ or $DU$ or $DDU$ or $DDDU$ and so on.

If $2$ "up"s is needed, the sequence needed must be $UUD$.

If $3$ "up"s is required, the sequence needed is $UUUD$.

\begin{align}E[K]=1\cdot \left(\frac14 +\frac14\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{2^k}\right)+ \sum_{k=2}^\infty  \frac{k}{2^{k+1}}=\frac14 \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac12}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{2^{k+1}}=1.5 \end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Oh I forgot the cases when we only have one heads

Comment: If the sequence is DU or DDU and so on, there is ***no*** up ***before*** the pair is achieved; the U and the pair arrive simultaneously.